# Loading GIF on Website after user clicked on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animated-gif

When a user clicks on a link within my website i would like to show a gif for as long as the browser waits for the response of the new page of the website.
All of that works fine with the exception, that in Firefox the animated gif wont be animated anymore. I guess it was made like that to safe recourses.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Maybe even in Jquery or JavaScript?

Comment: Do you load the gif after the user clicks?

Comment: Exactly. The user clicks and then the gif is display via javascript.

Comment: I would suggest you to pre-load the gif and keep it hidden until the user clicks on link. As far as I know, Firefox doesn't start animating a gif until it is full loaded.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the information.